# Syntax for allowedContent in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I don't really get the syntax of the `allowedContent` setting when creating an instance of CKEditor. I have seen some examples "separating" groups of elements with `;` but I cannot find an explanation to why this needs to be done.

The doc contains an example rule that looks like `p h1; a[!href]; *[id]`. What would be the difference to writing the same but without the semicolon `p h1 a[!href] *[id]`?

Answer (score 0):

In the following case you allow `p` and `h1` elements with no attributes and `a` only if it has `href`:

```
p h1; a[!href]
```

How could you achieve the same result without semicolon? Let's see if the following syntax could work:

```
p h1 a[!href]
```

There are two possible ways to parse it:

- the way we want,
- that all 3 tags require `href` (what does not make sense).

Of course we want to chose the first option. It means that only a tag name directly preceding the `[!href]` part is related to it and that all other tags have no attributes. But it means that you cannot do this:

```
p h1; link a[!href]
```

The current `allowedContent` syntax allows you to say that `link` and `a` have the same set of attributes, classes and styles. Without semicolon it would be impossible.